# Backward Compatibility in Windows Forms App built on .NET 4

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, compatibility

I have built an application using c# on .NET. My software will run on PCs having XP SP3 to Win 7. I did my research in deciding which version of .NET to use for development. Microsoft website clearly says that .NET 4 apps can run on XP SP3. I trusted them, built the app till a month where its halfway, I just had a test deployment & boooooom. Its not even starting up & gives errors that not all components required are installed. I researched and SQL Server 2008 couldnt be installed.

I've done the following:
- Tried to install .NET 4 on XP SP3. Gets installed easily. BUT SQL Server express 2008 (which my app uses) couldnt be installed, it says to install .NET 2
- IF I install .NET 2, I am not sure whether the app will run on Windows 7.

Please Help. My Client will kill me !

Comment: Why are you trying to install a piece of server software (SQL Server) on a Windows XP system??? .NET 4 works fine on XP SP3, but SQL Server 2008...

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 will run side by side without an issue.  In fact, Windows 7 comes preinstalled with .NET 2.0, though you may need to [enable it manually](https://superuser.com/a/39629/27724).

You may want to post a more detailed question with your errors, as there shouldn't be any insurmountable problems with any of what you're trying to do.  SQL Server 2008 Express, for instance, [should work fine on XP SP3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Application written for NET 2.0 works fine in Windows7.
But, instead of downgrading the framework library, I think you should check if your app really requires SqlServer 2008.
Perhaps you could simply downgrade to use [SqlServer Express 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21844) and recreate your database.
This will be less limiting from the point of view of your coding possibilities.